# Flutter Cloudfirestore: how to check whether field exists

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My Flutter app uses Firbase Cloudfirestore as its backend. Later I'll want to add new features to my app which would require new fields in a Firestore document. How can I check whether the field exists in the document and return a default value if it doesn't?

```
Stream<List<Car>> streamCars() {
    return _carsCollection.snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((document) => Car.fromDocumentSnapshot(document)).toList());
}

static Car fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
  return Car(
    id: snapshot.id,
    date: snapshot['date'] ?? Timestamp.now(),
    seats: snapshot['seats'] ?? 0,
    newFeature: snapshot['newFeature'] ?? '', // This field does not exist yet and throws error
  );
}
```

This throws the error:

```
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like so.

```
newFeature: (snapshot.data() as Map)['newFeature'] ?? ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static Car fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
  return Car(
    id: snapshot.id,
    date: snapshot['date'] ?? Timestamp.now(),
    seats: snapshot['seats'] ?? 0,
    newFeature: snapshot['newFeature']==null ?'tjhjhjh': '', // check it if is null will solve the error
  );
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. And isn't `a ?? b` the same as `a==null ? b : a`?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Jiger-patel thanks. In a different scenario, while adding objects if a particular row, "note" field not found in firestore document. The below might help.

for (var data in snapshot.data!.docs) {
          studyData.add(Study(
                    time: data['bp_time'].toDate(),
                    note: (data.data() as Map)['note'] ?? ''
  ));
}
```